# Ping "replies" from same computer with 'Destination host unreachable' (no route to other computer)

Tags: windows, routing, ping, networking

I've got two computers in a LAN behind a wireless router.

One has XP with ip 192.168.1.2

This one has W7 with ip 192.168.1.7

If I try to ping the other one from this computer, I get this:

```
C:\Users\Srekel>ping 192.168.1.2

Pinging 192.168.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.7: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.7: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.7: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.7: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Tracert gives the same result:

```
C:\Users\Srekel>tracert 192.168.1.2

Tracing route to 192.168.1.2 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1  Kakburken4 [192.168.1.7]  reports: Destination host unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

Although I can ping and tracert the router without any problems. I have disabled the firewalls on both computers. The router is set to use DHCP (if that matters).

Here is the output from "route".

```
C:\Users\Srekel>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13...00 25 86 df c6 89 ......TP-LINK Wireless N Adapter
 12...e0 cb 4e 26 b9 84 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2
 11...e0 cb 4e 26 be 94 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.7     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    276
      192.168.1.7  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.7    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.7    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 14     58 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 14     58 2001::/32                On-link
 14    306 2001:0:5ef5:73ba:881:20c1:3f57:fef8/128
                                    On-link
 14    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    306 fe80::881:20c1:3f57:fef8/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I've set up and debugged a few networks in my life but I'm not really an advanced network user, so I'm not sure what might be wrong. Any ideas? Oh, and pinging this computer from the other computer doesn't work either.

EDIT: Adding arp output:

```
C:\Users\Srekel>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.7 --- 0xd
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.1.1           00-1f-33-ef-28-01     dynamic
  192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Adding ipconfig...

```
C:\Users\Srekel>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Kakburken4
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TP-LINK Wireless N Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-25-86-DF-C6-89
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.7(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 09 April 2010 23:09:45
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 10 April 2010 23:09:45
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-CB-4E-26-B9-84
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-CB-4E-26-BE-94
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{74D5C406-894E-4000-8DE7-6AAEBF7C8382}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:73ba:881:20c1:3f57:fef8(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::881:20c1:3f57:fef8%14(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: I managed to solved the problem. Try to `repair` the `network bridge` connection on the server, and all the "repy from ....: destination host unreachable" are gone.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of cheap 802.11 APs and client cards out there with broken multicast* support, especially when encryption is enabled, and *especially* especially when WPA2 Mixed Mode (AES-CCMP simultaneously with TKIP) or 802.11i TSN (AES-CCMP and/or TKIP simultaneously with WEP) is enabled.

*Note: In 802.11, broadcast is a subset of multicast: it's a multicast that goes to *everyone*. So when I say "multicast", think "multicast/broadcast".

On 802.11, multicast is trickier in the AP -> client direction, because it has to be sent at a lowest-common-denominator multicast rate, it isn't ACKed or resent at the 802.11 layer, and if you have WPA or WPA2 encryption on, it has to be sent encrypted with a different key (the group key), and if you have WPA2 Mixed Mode or 802.11i TSN on, it has to be sent not only with a different key, but with a different cipher (a lowest-common-denominator cipher; TKIP in the case of WPA2 Mixed Mode, and WEP in the case of TSN).

One quick way to see if it's just multicast problem is to manually add static ARP entries on each machine, so they know the "IP address -> wireless MAC address" mappings of each other, and then see if you can ping. ARP uses broadcasts, so broken multicasts on an 802.11 network breaks the ability of a wireless client to receive ARP broadcasts when other clients are trying to look up the wireless client's MAC address. Without the ARP mapping, the ping frame can't be addressed at the 802.11 layer, so it can't be transmitted.

If static ARP mappings fixes it, try temporarily turning off all wireless encryption, then delete your static ARP mappings and try your test again. If ARP works this time, it's a sign that multicast is not *completely* broken on your 802.11 equipment, it's just broken when encryption is on.

About now, some might be asking, "But if broadcasts are broken, why did DHCP work? DHCP uses broadcasts!", and you're right that DHCP uses broadcasts, but in DHCP only the messages *from* the client *to* the server are broadcast. In the other direction, they're usually unicast. And it's only in the *to the client* direction that multicasts are tricky in 802.11.

Check with your AP and client card vendor for firmware and driver updates. Always buy Wi-Fi certified 802.11 gear, because the Wi-Fi certification testing specifically tests to ensure multicast works even when crypto is on. Please also "name and shame" the vendors of the AP and client card(s) in question.

When multicast is broken between an AP and a client, I can't think of an easy way to tell if the fault is with the AP or the client, other than process-of-elimination, by seeing if other brands of wireless clients have the same problem on that AP, and seeing if that wireless client has the same problem on other brands of APs.

---

The more advanced way to pin the blame on one end or the other is to use another machine that's not part of the test, but has an 802.11 card, to do an 802.11 monitor mode packet trace, starting from before the wireless client associates. Someone well-versed in 802.11 and WPA[2] key handshaking and the like can probably analyze it and find where to point fingers.

I do most of my networking work on Macs, so I can't walk you through getting 802.11 monitor mode packet traces on other platforms, but just in case you have a Snow Leopard (Mac OS X v10.6) box around, you can do:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/airportd en1 sniff 1  
[...run your test...]  
^C
```

...to do an 802.11 monitor mode capture, via en1, which is typically the built-in AirPort card on most Macs, on channel 1. Modify that if your AirPort card is not en1, or if your AP is not on channel 1.

Or you can do:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -z -c1  
sudo tcpdump -I -y IEEE802_11_radio -s0 -w monitorModeTrace.pcap  
[...run your test...]  
^C
```

(The `-c1` argument to the `airport` tool puts in the interface on channel 1; modify that to the channel your AP is on.)

Or you can run Wireshark, tshark, etc., but on the Mac you'll still need to use the `airport` command to set the channel and to force a disassociation.

Comment: Thanks, you led me to the right track! I'm going to wait and see if there are any problems with my solution, otherwise I'm going to add the answer (or can I change the accepted answer later?) Anyways, basically what I had to do was this:
http://superuser.com/questions/101293/windows-7-the-arp-entry-addition-failed-access-is-denied

Comment: @Srekel, a static ARP mapping only works around the problem. If your multicasts are broken, other protocols such as service discovery / browsing protocols will be broken too. I still think you should see if the problem is related to the wireless security method you're using, and also figure out if the AP or the client is to blame. If the AP is to blame, I hope you'll share the make/model/hardware-revision/firmware-version so others learn which product to avoid.

Comment: I have seen an AP where if you set "Group Key Update Period" to a nonzero value (enabling it), after some time (probably after it had changed the group key) it started causing problems with ARP, which only went away if you rebooted the AP. Took me some time to figure out "hm, so THAT is why it was zero by default - a nonzero value does not work correctly on this AP, so they simply changed the default!"

Comment: +1 I was wondering what the problem was. Wish I could double +1 for the mini wifi sniffing tutorial (I always just bust out kismet in a VM connected to a USB wifi adapter). Too bad srekel never came back to post what the real problem was.

Answer (score 4):

Are you certain the firewall on this system is disabled? I've seen this behavior in Windows 7 when it isn't. Otherwise, you could check your arp tables with `arp -a` to see if you have an entry for 192.168.1.2 at all.

EDIT:

Well, the arp output isn't listing an entry for 192.168.1.2, so your system doesn't appear to even be attempting to contact it. Is there a VPN or other security software involved here? Can you show the output of `ipconfig /all`?

EDIT2:

Well, I was hoping that `ipconfig` shouted out something obviously broken, but it doesn't. Can you ping other hosts on the network? Try 192.168.1.1. How about other hosts in the world? My favorite to ping in 4.2.2.2.

EDIT3:

Ok, lets look at things from the other side. Can you do a ping from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.7, then get the results of `arp -a`, `ipconfig /all`, and `route print` on that system?

EDIT4:

As one of the other posters suggests, you should also check your wireless router or access point to make sure it will allow connectivity between clients.

Good luck,

--jed

Comment: +1 one on checking for firewalls and "internet security solutions" that might mess with the IP stack.

Comment: Yup, when a firewall is configured to REJECT vs. DROP packets, it'll often respond with "destination host unreachable" vs. silently discarding packets.

Comment: Yep, the firewall is off as far as I can see. I updated the post with arp output, though I'm not sure what I use it for.

Comment: Added ipconfig. Thanks for trying to figure this out :) The only other security related things I've got enabled is Microsoft Securty Essentials (anti virus) and Spybot. Disabling them didn't help.

Comment: Yep - .1.1 is the router and I can ping it fine. I can also ping google.com fine. pinging 4.2.2.2 results in mostly "Request timed out" but also some replies where time > 500ms

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, 192.168.1.1 is the router and can ping it fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible your wireless router is not allowing communication between clients. It's common for wireless routers to deny communication between hosts that are connected to it via the WLAN interface. Some wireless routers have options in their setup program to allow/deny communication between clients.

Comment: Especially if you are running different firmware like DD-WRT or tomato.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today on a NetGear router.

I found out that - God knows why and when - in the **Advanced Wireless Settings** page (down in the left menu bar, name translated from Italian) the topmost check box **WPS Enabled** was flagged.

I think I've never actually set that on purpose and anyway I don't think I need it, standing its meaning as per Netgear Support page ["What is Wi-Fi Protected Setup (WPS) or NETGEAR's Push 'n' Connect?"](http://support.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/96/~/what-is-wi-fi-protected-setup-%28wps%29-or-netgear%27s-push-%27n%27-connect?).

And of course, after clearing that check and saving changes, the ping was working back again. More than that, my laptop's Windows 7 could access again shared folders on the other laptop's Windows 7. That was the main issue that caused this research.

BTW - following @goedson suggestion - it's worth to mention that the router has a so-called **PC Isolation** feature, which prevents machines on the LAN to see each other. This was turned off since the beginning, I've played with it and anyway it did not make any change.

Answer (score 0):

Weird stuff I tend to

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh ip int reset log
reboot -r -t 0
```